Estimation on function defined on diophantine approximation
Consider a convergent series $\sum_n a_n=1$ where $a_n\geq 0$. I am interested in a non-zero lower bound on the function
$$
S(t)=\sum_n a_n d(nt,\mathbb Z)^2
$$
where $d(nt,\mathbb Z)$ is the distance from $nt$ to the closest integer. I understand that a bound valid for every $t$ does not make sense, but I rather wish to evaluate integrals of the form
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{f(t)}{S(t)}dt
$$
where $f$ is smooth.
A more precise question would be: is there a good upper bound on
$$
\mathcal L(\{t\in [0,1]:S(t)\leq u\})
$$
for $u\in [0,1]$, where $\mathcal L$ is Lebesgue measure? The choice of the $a_n$ is up to you, under the constraint that infinitely many of them should be non zero. Maybe a geometric sequence is a good idea.
